# how does below query work

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone explain me how below query will work.. i have table called employee

```
id FirstName LastName   Email            Groupid
1 Paula      Brown    pb@testdomain.org    12
2 James      Smith    jim@test.co.uk       12
3 James      Connor   jc@tes.co.uk         13


select * from employee where groupid=12 AND id NOT IN (1) OR id NOT IN (2)
```

how does this query works? Am trying to understand how AND clause works with OR. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AND` has precedence over `OR`, so the condition is interpreted as

```
(group=12 but id <> 1) OR (id <> 2)
```

All three records match this condition:

```
1 Paula      Brown    pb@testdomain.org    12 -- id <> 2
2 James      Smith    jim@test.co.uk       12 -- group=12 and id <> 1
3 James      Connor   jc@tes.co.uk         13 -- id <> 2
```

If you are looking for a different order of evaluation, you can force it using parentheses.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. how will this query be interpreted      select * from employee where groupid=12 AND id IN (1) OR id IN (2)

Comment: @questborn - as `(group = 12 and id = 1) or (id = 2)`, so it'll match the first two records. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#i1034834) shows the precedence. If there's any possibility of ambiguity, including for someone trying to read the code later, I'd recommend always using parentheses to make it clear, even if you don't want to change the order of evaluation.